# AWS API Gateway returning HTTP code 400 while using query parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, aws-api-gateway, query-string

I created an API Gateway with a resource: /test. It's using proxy integration to invoke a Lambda function.

Now, I'd like to make a GET request to retrieve some data with the following query param: `/test?param={"test":1}`

But I keep getting a "400 Bad Request" response. If I pass `?param=test`, the Lambda function is getting invoked and I can access the key and value. But I'm currently unable to see any logs from API Gateway or the Lambda function.

Am I missing any configuration within API Gateway so I can pass the above to API Gateway?

What've I tried?

- Ran the service (I'm building a micro-service) locally and everything works as expected
- I've been reading up on [multiValueQueryStringParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format), tried adding `param` to `Query Strings` in `Method Request` for the resource in API Gateway. Still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated as I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out already!

Comment: unlike path parameters, query parameters needed not be setup within Api Gateway, they should be passed along to Lambda, Do you see any errors in Api Gateway logs or Lambda logs? what is the exact response body you got for 400 ?

Comment: Oddly enough, I discovered that when my Lambda function A called Lambda function B, the query params were being received by function B with no problem! But when I'm invoking Lambda function B from Postman, the 400 error comes up. API Gateway only returns the status code, and nothing body. Just to add another detail: I created the resource, added an ANY method, integrated the resource with a Lambda in a region and checked "use lambda proxy integration" checkbox before saving. Is there anything I might be missing that you may know?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your call literally ends in `/test?param={"test":1}` e.g., something like `https://123456asdf.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test?param={"test":1}`

If that's the case you are not escaping your url properly. Certain characters need to be "url encoded"

A quick Google search found this utility:
http://www.utilities-online.info/urlencode/

Off limit characters get encoded with a percent followed by a number. So your query should be:

`/test?param=%7B%22test%22%3A1%7D`

Most libraries will do the encoding for you when you try to send parameters. You only really need to worry about this if you are doing it manually ....

In Lambda you'll then see `{"test":1}` since Lambda "url-decodes" parameters.